# How can I insert dashes between each 2 odds numbers and asterisks between even numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, for-loop

How can I write a function that insert dashes ('-') between each two odd numbers and insert asterisks ('*') between each two even numbers?

For example: if num is 4005467930 the output should be: 40054*67-9-30. I Did not count zero as an odd or even number.
below is my code: I tried to use continue to loop over zero , but it didn't work. There is also dash('-') in the begining of the printed result. How can I overcome this

```
function StringChallenge(num) {

    let newString = num.toString();
    let result = '';
   
    for (let i = 0; i <newString.length; i++) {
      let previous_number = newString[i-1];
      let current_number = newString[i];

      if(current_number === 0 || previous_number === 0 ){
        result += current_number
        continue
      } else
        if(previous_number % 2 == 0 && current_number % 2 == 0) {
            result += "*" + current_number
            console.log(result)
        } else if(previous_number % 2 !== 0 && current_number % 2 !== 0) {
            result += "-" + current_number
            console.log(result)
        } else {
            result += current_number
            console.log(result)
        }
        
        
    }
    return result
}
console.log(StringChallenge(4005467930))   // -4*0*054*67-9-30; I want it to be: 40054*67-9-30 //
```

Comment: `0` is an even number btw

Comment: A few more suggestions for your assignment here too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758949/how-do-i-return-the-result-of-all-loops-in-javascript/73759150#73759150

Comment: @KonradLinkowski , I know **0** is an even number but I want to ignore it on purpose. can you help with that?

Comment: You start your loop at index `i = 0` and immediately say `let previous_number = newString[i-1];` That is not good.

Comment: @rossum Please explain better, It is giving me headache

Comment: You set `i = 0` at the start of your loop. Then you `let previous_number = newString[i-1];` That means you are trying to set `previous_number` to `newString[-1], when the `newString` array starts at index 0. Javascript does not have the error checking that most other languages have, which would have flagged the error.

Comment: I have made the correction but it still doesn't solve the problem. I really want to use for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that after you convert the number to string digits, you work with the values as though they are still numeric.  For the modulo calls (`%`) that happens to work, since JS does a numeric conversion if necessary.  But it won't work with the strict equality operator (`===`) when you compare with zero.  While the quickest fix would be to simply change these to the looser equality (`==`) check, I think it would be cleaner and more explicit to convert them to numbers, either like this:

```js
function StringChallenge (num) {
    let newString = num .toString ();
    let result = '';
   
    for (let i = 0; i < newString .length; i++) {
      let previous_number = Number (newString [i - 1])  // Change to number
      let current_number = Number (newString [i])       // ditto

      if (current_number === 0 || previous_number === 0 ){
        result += current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 == 0 && current_number % 2 == 0) {
        result += "*" + current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 !== 0 && current_number % 2 !== 0) {
        result += "-" + current_number
      } else {
        result += current_number
      }
    }
    return result
}

console .log (StringChallenge (4005467930))
```

or even better, converting them once up front, like this:

```js
function StringChallenge (num) {
    let digits = num .toString () .split ('') .map (Number)
    let result = ''
   
    for (let i = 0; i < digits .length; i++) {
      let previous_number = digits [i - 1]
      let current_number = digits [i]

      if (current_number === 0 || previous_number === 0 ){
        result += current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 == 0 && current_number % 2 == 0) {
        result += "*" + current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 !== 0 && current_number % 2 !== 0) {
        result += "-" + current_number
      } else {
        result += current_number
      }
    }
    return result
}

console .log (StringChallenge (4005467930))
```

There is still a bit of magic working here.  People were explaining problems because you're starting at index `0` and there `newString [i - 1]` will be `undefined`.  And `Number (undefined)` is `NaN`.  That will mean that each of your `if`/`else if` blocks will drop through, and the final `else` will just append the current number.  But depending on this feels odd to me, and I would suggest that you start with index `1` and start your result with the first digit, something like this:

```js
function StringChallenge (num) {
    let digits = num .toString () .split ('') .map (Number)
    let result = String (digits [0])  // changed
    //           v---------------------- changed
    for (let i = 1; i < digits .length; i++) {
      let previous_number = digits [i - 1]
      let current_number = digits [i]

      if (current_number === 0 || previous_number === 0 ){
        result += current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 == 0 && current_number % 2 == 0) {
        result += "*" + current_number
      } else if (previous_number % 2 !== 0 && current_number % 2 !== 0) {
        result += "-" + current_number
      } else {
        result += current_number
      }
    }
    return result
}

console .log (StringChallenge (4005467930))
```

---

However, if I were to solve this from scratch, I would probably prefer a `map` plus a `join` to your `for`-loop full of concatenations.  In my very different code style, it would probably look like this:

```js
const StringChallenge = (s, digits = [... (String (s))] .map (Number)) =>
  digits .map ((c, i, _, p = digits [i - 1], d = (c - p) % 2) => 
     (i == 0 || c == 0 || p == 0 || d != 0 ? '' : c % 2 == 0 ? '*' : '-') + c
  ) .join ('')

console .log (StringChallenge (4005467930))
```

Here we start by converting the input number into digits, then we map over all the digits, calling the current digit `c` and the index `i`, calculating the previous digit (`p`) and the difference (`d`) between them `mod 2`, and then prepending something to the character `c`: a blank space if `i` is zero, if either digit is zero, of if the mod-2 difference is *not* zero, a `*` if the digit is (non-zero) even, and a `-` if it's odd.

Then we simply join the results into a single string.

Answer (score 4):

We can try a simple regex approach here:

```js
function StringChallenge(num) {
    return num.replace(/(?<=[2468])(?=[2468])/g, "*")
              .replace(/(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])/g, "-");
}

var number = "4005467930";
console.log(number + " => " + StringChallenge(number));
```

Here is an explanation of the regex patterns:

- `(?<=[2468])(?=[2468])` this matches any point in the string surrounded on both sides by an even digit (excluding zero)
- `(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])` this matches any point in the string surrounded on both sides by an odd digit

Comment: Thank you, but can you please do it inside function? because it doesnt work inside my fucntion

Comment: I have made the edit you requested.

Comment: can you submit another answer for this same task using for loop? Please read my question again, I have modified the grammars